# Particular solution of given differential equation.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the particular solution of the differential equation:

$$(1+x^2) \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2xy=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

$y=0$ when $x=1$.

Could someone give me some hint to proceed in this question. I know how to deal $\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x) \cdot y=Q(x)$ but don't how to deal second order.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to get a simple solution. Maple 2015.1: $$y(x) = (x+I)*HeunC(0, 1, -1, 4*I, 1/2-2*I, 1/2-I*x*(1/2))*_C2+(x+I)*HeunC(0, 1, -1, 4*I, 1/2-2*I, 1/2-I*x*(1/2))*(Int(1/((x+I)^2*HeunC(0, 1, -1, 4*I, 1/2-2*I, 1/2-I*x*(1/2))^2), x))*_C1+HeunC(0, 1, -1, 4*I, 1/2-2*I, 1/2-I*x*(1/2))*(x+I)*((Int(1/((x+I)^2*HeunC(0, 1, -1, 4*I, 1/2-2*I, 1/2-I*x*(1/2))^2), x))*(Int((x+I)*HeunC(0, 1, -1, 4*I, 1/2-2*I, 1/2-I*x*(1/2))/(x^2+1)^2, x))-(Int((x+I)*HeunC(0, 1, -1, 4*I, 1/2-2*I, 1/2-I*x*(1/2))*(Int(1/((x+I)^2*HeunC(0, 1, -1, 4*I, 1/2-2*I, 1/2-I*x*(1/2))^2), x))/(x^2+1)^2, x))) $$